# как всплывают события в yii2

Tags: yii2

Кто-нибудь, может объяснить, как всплывают события в yii2?
В js всё понятно, сначала до цели вниз, а потом по предкам обратно вверх и где то в родителях можно перехватить событие. 
А где 100% перехватить событие в yii2? допустим интересует событие EVENT_AFTER_INSERT.
Я так понимаю для этого нужно объявлять отдельные модуль, который кидать в бутстрап секцию конфига и там ловить событие?
Какие-нибудь ещё варианты есть?

Comment: Здесь смотрел? https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/concept-events/
и тут http://klisl.com/yii2_events.html

Comment: да, смотрел. Как повесить событие, как удалить, как выполняются обработчики если их несколько на событии, какие событие и т.д. А вот область видимость событий не рассмотрена, или я что то упускаю. Может не внимательно читал